# If anchor points to folder, should it ends with "/"?

Tags: html

Let's say I have this folder structure on my local server:

```
root/
  index.html
  some/
    folder/
      index2.html
```

My local server will automaticly load .html file in given directory.
Should I point to index2.html from index.html like this:

```
<a href="some/foler">link</>
```

or like this:

```
<a href="some/foler/">link</>
```

Which way is right?

Comment: You can reference it either way.  I tend to reserve using the back-slash at the end of file paths when providing URL's and using self-control for file paths.

Comment: Check this question in the webmasters stack exchange: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/does-it-make-a-difference-if-your-url-path-ends-in-a-trailing-slash-or-not